# Изменить audio-файл

Tags: android, аудио

Есть аудио файл на sdcard. Как изменить его так, чтобы он воспроизводился задом наперед?
Или объясните, как записать с микрофона звук и воспроизвести задом наперед.

Answer (score 1):

FF MPG библиотеки в помощь.